# How to show the Instagram followers counter in my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, instagram, counter

How to show the Instagram followers counter in my WordPress website see the screen shot. [Screenshots Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQo8b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check below code?

```
$api_key = 'API_KEY';
$user_id = 'UID';
$data = @file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$user_id/?client_id=$api_key");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
echo '<pre/>';
print_r($data);
echo $data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
```

Comment: thanks i thinks API_KEY replace with client Id and UID replace with client secret right ?

Comment: Could you please my answer is mark as correct ? so some one helpful for this